# How to render html.erb conditionally from javascript (WebGL check)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I want to decide which content to render in a Rails app depending on WebGL support.

I know I can check for WebGL from JS

```
 if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext) {

     return;   }
```

But how can I use that to decide what to render in html.erb?

I want something like

```
 if (!window.WebGLRenderingContext) {

       // Use some <%= rails_helper %>

        }else{

    // <%= use_another_rails_helper %>
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this you are looking for?

```
 if(!window.WebGLRenderingContext) {
   $("#div_id").html(<%= rails_helper %>);
  }
else {
   $("#div_id").html(<%= use_another_rails_helper %>);
 }
```

Comment: yes that is actually something that I ended up doing. I used js.erb and rendered the partials from there with .html() and .insertAfter()